# Why is there an opencv2 folder inside OpenCV 3.x?

Tags: opencv

Is this just for backwards compatibility, for people who have been developing for years with OpenCV 2 and then want to use OpenCV 3 without having to rewrite all their legacy code?  Or is this related to a fundamental design decision the creators of OpenCV 3 opted for?  For instance, when I look up imread examples for OpenCV 3, they have `#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"`.  Is this just the way you refer to certain files/functions in OpenCV 3, or is there an "OpenCV 3 way" out there that many people don't use, because they just prefer the old syntax/style of various operations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version number in the include path refers to the API version. C-based OpenCV was API v1, C++-based OpenCV is API v2.

The library versions are now 3.x, but they are still using the same C++-based API. Thus OpenCV builds still have their header files in opencv2 folders.

Comment: Hmmmm... okay, that's a pretty good explanation.  Still seems a little bit odd to me from a design perspective, but at least that answers my latent question of "when people refer to opencv2 within OpenCV 3, is there an (approximately) equal way to accomplish the same task without referring to opencv2?"  And it seems the answer is no.

Comment: Just to add a little more to the answer, in python, you will see the same issue. cv2 is used and it is reality opencv 3... and probably in opencv 4 they will still use the same name

Comment: Yeah, it’s called `opencv2` in OpenCV 5.